# Google Cloud messaging php Curl timeout

Tags: php, curl, google-cloud-messaging

Does anyone know how what might be causing this type of error sometimes i try to execute my php file?

> Curl error: Operation timed out after 0 milliseconds with 0 out of 0
>   bytes received

I get this error very often when I try to load my php file with GCM code, but sometimes I do not get it.

Comment: So is it "everytime" or "sometimes I do not get it"?

Comment: so sorry, its sometimes!.. most times infact

Comment: possible duplicate of [GCM curl operation time out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31502664/gcm-curl-operation-time-out)